# Implement Office 365 Authentication on ASP.NET MVC 5 (.NET Framework 4.5.1)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, office365, single-sign-on

Good day everyone

Can I integrate Office 365 authentication to oldest framework (.NET framework 4.5.1), we have an existing application that are using the old framework, and we want to use the Office 365 authentication on this application, but I have no idea regarding this, for .NET Core (.NET 5 to 7) I already done it, but for the old framework, I have no idea.

Thanks and regards

I tried to search on google but no worked.